# Storing a Bitmap in Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, png, steganography

I am manipulating the values of pixels in a bitmap.
In a particular run of the program in Android
The source values of Red Green and Blue were 45  13  0
After manipulating the values the values were Red Green Blue 44 9 7

Now i create a new bitmap from these pixel values and store it using

```
Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.compress.PNG,100,fout);
```

and access the pixel back using

```
bmp.getPixel(0,0,value);
```

The new values of Red Green and Blue were 49 16 0 which is neither the manipulated value nor the original value,What may be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The bitmap `compress` function compresses the bitmap file.

Use `Bitmapfactory` to decode the resource and you will get back actual bitmap.